# URL as URL's get parameters - problem with "&" 

Tags: php, url-encoding

There is script that receives another url as GET parameter:

```
script.php?file=http://www.google.com&id=123
```

The problem is:
when url has parameter itself, it is used as script's parameter, not that url's parameter:

```
script.php?file=http://www.google.com?q=adsf&lang=en&id=123
```

URL is `http://www.google.com?q=adsf&lang=en`, but it is chopped after `&`, because it is viewed as related to `script.php` itself.

What can I do about this?
I tired to replace `&` with `%26`, but url get broken with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the value with the [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

If you’re using PHP, use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) (or [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) if [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) is expected):

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com?q=adsf&lang=en';
echo 'script.php?file='.rawurlencode($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL encode the entire URL that you are passing as a parameter to another url (your script). %26 is the correct encoding for an &. Just make sure you decode it server-side before using it. You don't say what language(s) you're using, but most, inc javascript and php have native URL encoding functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to encode every special character like this:

```
script.php?file=http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%3fq%3dadsf%26lang%3den&id=123
```

although it might be better and easier to use `rawurlencode()`.

Also, read [this](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) about URL encoding.